# How to use Yii without jQuery?

Tags: yii2

Unfortunately, the company I work for already has a lot of client-side code written for Mootools, and they don't seem to like each other very much. :S

No matter what I do, I can't seem to stop jQuery getting included in every page. Any ideas?

Comment: From the [yii website](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/394/javascript-and-ajax-with-yii/): Yii often uses Javascript, even when the developper does not explicitly ask for it. The framework has chosen the library JQuery which is included in Yii's distribution.

Answer (score 1):

By default Yii application templates make use of `AppAsset`

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

that depends on `YiiAsset` asset bundle, and Yii built-in widgets use jQuery heavily. Remove 'yii\web\YiiAsset' dependency if you don't plan to use Yii client-side features.

Answer (score 1):

go to your AppAsset.php and remove `yii\web\YiiAsset`.

also, go to your main layout file, remove the default NavBar because it will call jquery.js to render

```php
#remove the default main menu below
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    ],
]);
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
        ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
        Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
            ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']] :
            ['label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']],
    ],
]);
NavBar::end();
```

This will remove jquery.js from Yii2. I would recommend you to switch from MooTools to Jquery if you can. It makes your life alot easier.

Answer (score 1):

[from docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles) you can disable the *jQuery asset bundle* by associating false to it :

```php
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => false,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

But you need to consider that many [jQuery built in widgets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-widget-jui.html) will stop working.

I don't know much about Mootools, but if it supports AJAX and you are building a complete fronted on top of it then you may also consider using [Yii as a REST Service](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html).